# How to convert date into "2015-05-14T23:00:00" format - Jquery

Tags: javascript, date-formatting

I'm trying to convert a date string into the above format:

```
var today = new Date();
today.getDate() - 7; //gives me 14 - considering today is May21
data['startDate'] = today.getDate() - 7; //now data['startDate'] = 14;
```

how can i convert this `14` into `2015-05-14T23:00:00`format??

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```js
// --------------------- Custom function to convert date format into whatever required ---
// Function to convert date - Please see the links section to get to know where I found this.
var dateFormat = function () {
    var token = /d{1,4}|m{1,4}|yy(?:yy)?|([HhMsTt])\1?|[LloSZ]|"[^"]*"|'[^']*'/g,
        timezone = /\b(?:[PMCEA][SDP]T|(?:Pacific|Mountain|Central|Eastern|Atlantic) (?:Standard|Daylight|Prevailing) Time|(?:GMT|UTC)(?:[-+]\d{4})?)\b/g,
        timezoneClip = /[^-+\dA-Z]/g,
        pad = function (val, len) {
            val = String(val);
            len = len || 2;
            while (val.length < len) val = "0" + val;
            return val;
        };

    // Regexes and supporting functions are cached through closure
    return function (date, mask, utc) {
        var dF = dateFormat;

        // You can't provide utc if you skip other args (use the "UTC:" mask prefix)
        if (arguments.length == 1 && Object.prototype.toString.call(date) == "[object String]" && !/\d/.test(date)) {
            mask = date;
            date = undefined;
        }

        // Passing date through Date applies Date.parse, if necessary
        date = date ? new Date(date) : new Date;
        if (isNaN(date)) throw SyntaxError("invalid date");

        mask = String(dF.masks[mask] || mask || dF.masks["default"]);

        // Allow setting the utc argument via the mask
        if (mask.slice(0, 4) == "UTC:") {
            mask = mask.slice(4);
            utc = true;
        }

        var _ = utc ? "getUTC" : "get",
            d = date[_ + "Date"](),
            D = date[_ + "Day"](),
            m = date[_ + "Month"](),
            y = date[_ + "FullYear"](),
            H = date[_ + "Hours"](),
            M = date[_ + "Minutes"](),
            s = date[_ + "Seconds"](),
            L = date[_ + "Milliseconds"](),
            o = utc ? 0 : date.getTimezoneOffset(),
            flags = {
                d:    d,
                dd:   pad(d),
                ddd:  dF.i18n.dayNames[D],
                dddd: dF.i18n.dayNames[D + 7],
                m:    m + 1,
                mm:   pad(m + 1),
                mmm:  dF.i18n.monthNames[m],
                mmmm: dF.i18n.monthNames[m + 12],
                yy:   String(y).slice(2),
                yyyy: y,
                h:    H % 12 || 12,
                hh:   pad(H % 12 || 12),
                H:    H,
                HH:   pad(H),
                M:    M,
                MM:   pad(M),
                s:    s,
                ss:   pad(s),
                l:    pad(L, 3),
                L:    pad(L > 99 ? Math.round(L / 10) : L),
                t:    H < 12 ? "a"  : "p",
                tt:   H < 12 ? "am" : "pm",
                T:    H < 12 ? "A"  : "P",
                TT:   H < 12 ? "AM" : "PM",
                Z:    utc ? "UTC" : (String(date).match(timezone) || [""]).pop().replace(timezoneClip, ""),
                o:    (o > 0 ? "-" : "+") + pad(Math.floor(Math.abs(o) / 60) * 100 + Math.abs(o) % 60, 4),
                S:    ["th", "st", "nd", "rd"][d % 10 > 3 ? 0 : (d % 100 - d % 10 != 10) * d % 10]
            };

        return mask.replace(token, function ($0) {
            return $0 in flags ? flags[$0] : $0.slice(1, $0.length - 1);
        });
    };
}();

// Some common format strings
dateFormat.masks = {
    "default":      "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss",
    shortDate:      "m/d/yy",
    mediumDate:     "mmm d, yyyy",
    longDate:       "mmmm d, yyyy",
    fullDate:       "dddd, mmmm d, yyyy",
    shortTime:      "h:MM TT",
    mediumTime:     "h:MM:ss TT",
    longTime:       "h:MM:ss TT Z",
    isoDate:        "yyyy-mm-dd",
    isoTime:        "HH:MM:ss",
    isoDateTime:    "yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss",
    isoUtcDateTime: "UTC:yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:MM:ss'Z'"
};

// Internationalization strings
dateFormat.i18n = {
    dayNames: [
        "Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat",
        "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"
    ],
    monthNames: [
        "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec",
        "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
    ]
};

// For convenience...
Date.prototype.format = function (mask, utc) {
    return dateFormat(this, mask, utc);
};


// ----------- Code specific to your question -----------------------------------------

// Date preparation and answer specific to your question goes here.
    var today = new Date();
    var data = Array();
    var prevDate = today.getDate() - 7; //gives me 14 - considering today is May21
    if(prevDate > 0) {
      today.setDate(prevDate);
    }

    today = dateFormat(today, "yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:ss");
    data['startDate'] = today;

//    2015-05-14T23:00:00
    $("#date").html(data['startDate']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="date">Click "Run" run the JS Code snippet</h1>
```

Reference links:

1. [W3Schools Date reference on JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_methods.asp)
2. [W3Schools - setDate](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp)
3. [DateFormat function I found online](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)

Hope this was helpful to you!

Cheers!

Comment: What happens if `today.getDate() - 7` is negative?

Comment: It may go wrong. So the thing to do is check and validate if it is not a negative before you use the setDate method. That way you are okay with the above answer right?
I will update it for you! :-)

Comment: So your solution is that for the first week of the month the code does nothing?

Comment: @Randika, mmm I doubt that's what the OP wants. I've posted an answer of my own.

Comment: @Juhana hey it's up to user1234 to decide what the code should be doing when it's the first week of the month right? It's certainly going in the else part of the if-else block. 

The question is just about
"how can i convert this 14 into 2015-05-14T23:00:00format??"
:-)

Comment: Apologies, it appears that `Data.prototype.setDate()` will reliably accept zero and negative numbers these days.

Comment: Sure? Good to know that! Anyway I've modified the answer much than it was before! I don't know why that somebody has voted it down! :/

Comment: This is incredibly complex for something that could be done in literally 5 lines of code.

Comment: @Juhana Yup that's true!
Specially that Date format conversion part!

I don't know why that somebody had voted down my answer before!

Comment: I don't think you understood my comment but never mind.

Comment: Thanks@Randika for the answer and xplanation as well

Answer (score 2):

Use [toISOString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString).

```
var pattern = 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss';
var now = new Date();
console.log( now.toISOString().substr(0, pattern.length) );
```